# Is Windows 8 OS file size smaller footprint?

Tags: windows-8

I wonder if Windows 8 OS file size is smaller footprint when freshly installed? My hard disk needs a bit of cleaning? Does it work?

Comment: By smaller footprint, do you mean files on a Windows 8 system take less space? Could be a different file system cluster size, though your question isn't very clear.

Comment: No, I don't mean the hard disk cluster size. I mean Windows-8 OS takes   small size footprint?

Comment: Do you mean whether Windows 8 will take up less disk space right after a fresh installation, compared to when it's been used for some time? If so, then yes. That's true for any operating system, in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 uses the same default cluster sizes as Windoes 7 in every offically supported filesystem.

If you are asking if Windows 8 requires less disk space to install than Windows 7, no.  It's larger. For home edition it's about 25% larger.

Comment: ..and larger as patches are added.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 includes a [new option to delete replaced Windows Updates to reduce the size of the WinSxS folder](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/153742-dism-improvements-in-windows-8/page__view__findpost__p__1015509). Run the disk cleanup wizzard and select the option "Windows Update cleanup":

[image]

[image]

[image]

After the reboot the files are deleted from the WinSxS folder.

[image]

After doing this, you can save a lot of HDD space and a reinstall is not necessary.