# Win 8 after BSOD huge amount of diskspace is missing

Tags: windows-8, bsod, disk-space

Recently got a BSOD on my PC without a reason (in Win8 it looks much funnier :)), after that I've notised that around 10gb on system partition space is missing. I've checked and cleaned memory dumps, temporary files and so on...but freed only 1gb of hard drive space...I've noticed that WinSxS folder is very big, but I don't remember how big it was before this accident and do not want to touch it right now. Any suggestions? Maybe story sounds familiar?
Thanks.

Update.
Restoring last backup worked like a charm, but still this situation makes no sense...Anyway I think case is closed, thanks everyone!

Comment: presumably you have hidden and system files set to "viewable". How much physical memory is installed?

Comment: I have 8gb ram on board. And I've tryed all built in system cleaning tools. I've got an idea of restoring last backup on system partition, maybe it will lead me somewhere.

Comment: The WinSXS folder is suppose to exist it will reduce in size over a period of time. You should not worry about the size of the WinSXD folder.  If you want help with the BSOD you have to post information on the BSOD.

Answer (score 1):

Run [TreeSizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/)

[image]

or [WizTree](http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wiztree-finds-the-files-and-folders-using-the-most-disk-space-on-your-hard-drive/)

[image]

to see what other files or folders use so much space. In Win8 you can run [disk cleanup to cleanup Windows Updates and reduce the WinSxS size](https://superuser.com/questions/556002/is-windows-8-os-file-size-smaller-footprint/556153#556153).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The WinSxS folder can get quite large. Unfortunately, you cannot really do anything about it short of uninstalling programs you don't need.

The size of that folder is probably a coincidence: I am guessing it was that way and you only noticed it because you were looking for problems.

I myself once had the winsxs folder balloon up to about 16gb. Note that the size reported may be much larger than what is actually being used, because winsxs is essentially multiple links to single files, and windows explorer cannot tell that the 13 references to a single 1k file is 1k not 13k.

See ( http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2008/09/17/what-is-the-winsxs-directory-in-windows-2008-and-windows-vista-and-why-is-it-so-large.aspx ) for an overview of Windows Side-by-side Assembly

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've just checked WinSxS contents, last file updates were three days ago and disk space became missing only today...

Comment: @da_sann - Which means the WinSXS is the correct size and has nothing to do with your missing storage space which isn't missing since its actually being used.